# Bokeh plot - custom categorical tick labels

Tags: bokeh

I'm trying to add an axis to a Bokeh plot in Python, with ticks at locations specified *and* labels as specified.

The plot I am making is a collection of daily data, but I am not using `x_axis_type="datetime"` because I do not want to assign a specific year to the data. That is, I am plotting data for the years 1950-2015 but I want the axis to say only "1 January", not "1-January-2000".

Originally I was using a CategoricalAxis, but this crowds out the labels because it places one for each of 366 ticks. I would like to reduce this to around 12 ticks to show each month.

I am able to use a LinearAxis to place the ticks in the location that I want, which is the first date of each month. However the tick labels are numeric and I would like to use string labels instead.

How can I change the tick labels to use a specific string?

```
# Remove default axis
p.xaxis.visible = False

# Add custom axis
ticker = FixedTicker()
ticker.ticks = first_day_of_month
xaxis = LinearAxis(ticker=ticker)
p.add_layout(xaxis, 'below')
```

1st attempt using standard CategoricalAxis, the x-axis is crowded:
[image: Using CategoricalAxis. Crowded out x-axis]

2nd attempt using code as posted, I want to change the numbers to labels:
[image: Custom LinearAxis. No labels on x-axis]

EDIT

The `DatetimeTickFormatter` was not immediately useful because the source format for the data was not a proper date. The x data is actually strings in the form "mmdd", eg "1230", which is why I was using CategoricalAxis in the first place.

Using `FuncTickFormatter` has been successful, if a little cumbersome. I'm using the code below which gives basically what I want.

```
CustomFuncTickFormatter = FuncTickFormatter(code = '''
return {0: 'January', 366: '', 335: 'December', 305: 'November', 274: 'October', 244: 'September', 213: 'August', 182: 'July', 152: 'June', 121: 'May', 91: 'April', 60: 'March', 31: 'February'}
[tick]
''')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `x_axis_type="datetime"`, `FixedTicker` and a custom instance of `DatetimeTickFormatter` ([documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter)) with all fields set to `[%d %m]`. If that doesn't work for some reason, you can always use `FuncTickFormatter` ([documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.FuncTickFormatter)).

Comment: This worked using `FuncTickFormatter`. I updated the question to add some information about why `DatetimeTickFormatter` wasn't working for me.